# Completely wipe all Windows 7 backup & restore settings

Tags: windows-7, windows-backup

How can I completely wipe all setting of Windows 7 backup & restore feature?

Currently it looks like this:
[image]

And I want to return to this:
[image]

How this is possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resetting Windows 7's backup parameters](https://superuser.com/questions/410329/resetting-windows-7s-backup-parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete the backup schedule, you need to turn of the schedule.

On the first screen (Control Panel\System and Security\Backup and Restore), click 'Turn of schedule'

Answer (score 0):

To delete a Windows 7 backup manually:

[image: Delete backup]

click 'Change Settings', you should see this:

[image: Change Settings]

Click 'View Backups' and delete your backup file.